# How to search and remove specific key:value entries from a python List-Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

how do we search / compare key:values and remove the entire row from the list ?

want to remove the entire row from the list for specific occurrences of  (key:value) "activity:insert" from the list-dictionary.

i tried the below code  , but its not able to remove the rows having the specific key:value pair

```
for k in jsod:
    if key in ('activity') and k[activity] == 'insert':
        del k[key]
```

```
[OrderedDict([('name', 'pageshift'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'dataupdate'), ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)]),
 OrderedDict([('name', 'bigdata'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'freeze'), ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)]),
 OrderedDict([('name', 'spark'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'dataupdate'), ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)]),
 OrderedDict([('name', 'django'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'insert'), ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)])]
```

Comment: So, you have a `list` of `OrderedDict` and you want to delete that `OrderedDict` from the `list` if a key-value pair `('activity', 'insert')` is in it. Is that your question?

Comment: yes @Tarun  ..my Bad need to edit the Question

Comment: I just added my answer. (:

Answer (score 1):

```py
for k in jsod:
    if k["activity"]=='insert':
        jsod.remove(k)
```

In your question, you were removing the key:value pair from the OrderedDict, not removing the OrderedDict from the list. In the code I have written above, I have changed it to remove the whole OrderedDict (the row as you call it) from the list.

EDIT:
Here is a whole program that shows this working with activity = False:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

jsod=[OrderedDict([('name', 'pageshift'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'dataupdate'), ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)]),
 OrderedDict([('name', 'bigdata'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'freeze'), ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)]),
 OrderedDict([('name', 'spark'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'dataupdate'), ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)]),
 OrderedDict([('name', 'django'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'insert'), ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)]),
 OrderedDict([('name', 'django'), ('value', ''), ('activity', False), ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)])] 

key_to_remove="activity"
value_to_remove=False

for k in jsod:
    if k[key_to_remove]==value_to_remove:
        jsod.remove(k)

print(jsod)
```

This prints:

```py
[OrderedDict([('name', 'pageshift'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'dataupdate'), ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)]), 
OrderedDict([('name', 'bigdata'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'freeze'), ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)]),
OrderedDict([('name', 'spark'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'dataupdate'), ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)]), 
OrderedDict([('name', 'django'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'insert'), ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)])]
```

This shows the 5th OrderedDict with ("activity",False) was removed.

Comment: ..thanks , is the expected to work for a boolean key value ? currently when i am trying to compare with a boolean key:value  , its not deleting the rows from the list

```
for k in jsod:
    if k["activity"] == 'False':
        jsod.remove(k)
```

Comment: @shirop This should work for any key value pair. Replace ```"activity"``` with the key and ```"insert"``` with the value you want to match. It may need some try/except statements added if you can't guarantee the key will be in every OrderedDIct.

Comment: doesn't seems to work for boolean ('activity',False)  key:value pairs

Comment: @shirop, I just tested it and it worked for me. What was the issue you were running into?

Comment: am trying to remove the rows from the list for all boolean value=False as in ('activity', False) , but the rows still seems to be present after the jsod.remove(k) operations on the list

Comment: @shirop, in your example you provided, none of the keys of "value" have a value of False.  Is that the issue? An empty string does not equal False.

Comment: yes am trying to search and remove a specific ordered dict where the key:value pair is ('activity', False)

Comment: @shirop, I have updated my answer to include a full example which removes the boolean value.

Comment: thanks  ..for some reason out of total x number of entries in the list , only few with ("activity", False) are getting deleted from the list , not sure why is that happening.
when trying to print(k) , its printing out all the rows as expected. for some reason list.remove(x) is not working as expected

Comment: Wait, are you deleting whole rows (what your original question says and what my answer does), or individual entries within a row?

Comment: whole row in the list-ordered dictionary ..entire row

Comment: ok i have worked around the problem now , seems like if you try to remove an entry from a list while trying to iterate over it at the same time it might cause issues with the remove. i have created a new list by filtering on ("activity",True) and its working as expected..Thanks for your help appreciate the same

Comment: @shirop, oh, yes that makes sense. Forgot about that behavior. Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

jsod = [OrderedDict(
    [('name', 'pageshift'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'dataupdate'), ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)]),
        OrderedDict(
            [('name', 'bigdata'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'freeze'), ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)]),
        OrderedDict(
            [('name', 'spark'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'dataupdate'), ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)]),
        OrderedDict(
            [('name', 'django'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'insert'), ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)])]

for each in jsod:
    if each['activity'] == 'insert':
        jsod.remove(each)

print(jsod)
```

This should do the job.

Comment: ..thanks  ..the above is not working for a boolean key:value like below
('activity',False) any clue why ?

Comment: `if not each['activity']:` - this has to be the if the condition for booleans

Comment: not working for ('activity',False) key:value entries

Comment: no error , the row still exists after the jsod.remove(p)  operations

Answer (score 0):

Using the dict `get` method might work better with booleans. This will remove all the `OrderedDicts` with any of the pairs in the `badpairs` list:

```
    results = make_dict_list()
    badpairs = (("activity", False), ("activity", "insert")) 
    for pair in badpairs:
        for i, x in enumerate(results):
            if x.get(pair[0]) == pair[1]:     #get doesn't throw KeyError
                print('HIT!')
                del(results[i])               #specific indexing rather than del(x)
            else: print('MISS!') 
        print("----------------") 
    print(results)
```

Here's a function to generate the OrderedDict from lists of tuples, including a case of `("activity",False)`:

```
from copy import deepcopy
from collections import OrderedDict

def make_dict_list() -> list:
    """returns list of [OrderedDict for each list of (key, value) pairs]"""
    temp = OrderedDict()

    A0 = [('name', 'pageshift'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'dataupdate'),
          ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)]

    A1 = [('name', 'bigdata'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'freeze'),
          ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)]

    A2 = [('name', 'spark'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'dataupdate'),
          ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)]

    A3 = [('name', 'django'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'insert'),
          ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)]

    A4 = [('name', 'pageshift'), ('value', ''), ('activity', False),
          ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)]

    mydicts = [A0, A1, A2, A3, A4]

    results = []

    for dictsets in mydicts:
        for pair in dictsets:
            temp[pair[0]] = pair[1]
        results.append(deepcopy(temp))   #load list with OrderedDict, clear & reload
        temp.clear()

    return results
```